# How do I use 7-Zip CLI for Windows to create .tar.gz archives?

Tags: windows, compression, tar, 7-zip, gzip

How can I use the 7-Zip CLI (*7za.exe*) on Windows to create .tgz archives, as I use `tar zcvf archive.tgz source_files` on Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now Windows supports a native tar command:

```
tar -cvzf output.tar.gz input_dir
```

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354853/how-to-create-tar-gz-file-using-powershell).

Answer (score 39):

If you'd like to do it in a one-liner:

`7za.exe a -ttar -so -an source_files | 7za.exe a -si archive.tgz`

The `-an` switch tells 7-Zip not to parse the archive_name command line parameter that's normally required.

Comment: note: if you have no 7za.exe in your 7zip-folder you can also use 7zg.exe if available

Comment: In my case, neither 7za.exe nor 7zg.exe was there, but 7z.exe was.

Comment: tar is required becausa a tgz or tar.gz is a tar file which has been gzipped. 7zip just don't have the ability to do all of it in just one step, so you have to pipe the output of the command which tars your files into the one that gzips your tar ^^. This is why when yopu open a tar.gz in 7zip you see a tar file inside.

Comment: @DGoiko I know that part -- I just didn't understand why the `archive.tar` *filename* is required when the data is being streamed to stdout.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that gz needed the internal filename in order to be properly displayed, but maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 7):

If you're just compressing 1 file into the tarball then `7za a archive.tgz source_file` will work.

If you want to add lots of files to the tar then you need to do it in two steps:
Create the tar `7za a archive.tar source_files`
Then compress it `7za a archive.tgz archive.tar`

And, optionally, delete the 'temporary' tar `del archive.tar`

Comment: I wish the one-liner worked for file-collections instead of just individual files! Thx for the heads up.