# How do I use 7-Zip GUI for Windows to create .tar.gz files?

Tags: tar, 7-zip, gui, gzip

How can I use the 7-Zip GUI on Windows to create `.tar.gz` files?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/339931/how-do-i-use-7-zip-for-windows-to-create-tar-gz-archives

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.random-host.com/blogs/creating-targz-file-7-zip):

> As a GZIP compressed archive can contain only one file, 7-Zip won't
>   offer you GZIP compression if you try to compress a folder or multiple
>   files at once. When you choose TAR, you can't select any compression
>   algorithm.
>
> The trick is, that you have to create a TAR archive first. You can then put that single TAR file into 7-Zip and it will finally offer you the ability to compress that file using GZIP.